# 120v breaker, 240v output

Tags: electrical

I am a pool service guy and a couple times i have stumbled across this, and always told the customer to contact a licensed electrician to resolve the situation. Breaker at the box that controls the pump is single pole 120v, power coming out at the end is 240v. It seems they either split the line at some point and then recombined the two hot lines to form 240v or are combining two breakers together. In one instance a switch changed it from 120v when off to 240v when on. How is this possible? What happens to the neutral line if you are just ignoring it and using the two hot lines to make 240v? I am sorry i did not have time to disassemble all of the wiring leading to it to placate my curiosity. Obviously this seems highly unsafe.

Comment: did you also measure both black and white relative to ground?

Comment: were there 2 black wires or just one?

Comment: sounds like half the 240 is unswitched ... only legal on the klingon home planet.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question, but we'll need more info to help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: I can't answer it because we don't know exactly what's there but it is definitely unsafe and sounds like someone took some short cuts to get 240V to the pump.

Comment: Black and White wire each measured 120v to ground.

Comment: "What happens to the neutral if you are just ignoring it..." - It isn't being ignored, it just isn't there. Not all loads need a neutral. Power flows in through one hot line (240V) and out the other. The neutral is just a center common point which splits the 240 in half. So hot A to neutral gets 120 and hot B to neutral gets 120. Hot A to hot B gets 240 though. Neutral is white, but not all white wires are neutral. If a white wire isn't being used as neutral, it's supposed to be marked in some way to let people know that it is actually hot.

Comment: And more directly to answer you; the only way to get 240 would be from connecting to a double pole breaker or two single pole breakers. In the case of using single pole breakers, they would require a handle tie to trip together. If neither of these are in the panel, then they are likely just missing the handle tie.

Comment: It sounds like a mwbc a multi wire branch circuit. Today they require a handle tie but when I first started they did not and folks moved them around with out realizing what they have done.

Comment: it sounds to me that someone just wired the wiring like any 120v circuit would be done but hot-wired the white wire to the other hot side instead of the neutral bus. he probably knew just enough that he'd get 240v that way.